# Interesting numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was doing some math problems when I came across some interesting numbers such as:

$1^3+5^3+3^3=153$

$4^3+0^3+7^3=407$

$3^3+7^3+0^3=370$

$3^3+7^3+1^3=371$

$8^4+2^4+0^4+8^4=8208$

My question is:

Is there a number of this family which doesn't contain $0,1$

What is the general formula for constructing such numbers?

Comment: I thinks I saw an article on Wolfram mathworld on such numbers.

Comment: What is the family, exactly? Numbers of the form $\sum^n_1 a_i^n$?

Comment: please share the link..

Comment: @RossMillikan Make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are given in [oeis.org/A005188](http://oeis.org/A005188) assuming the exponent should be the same as the number of digits

Answer (score 3):

There is a neat article on wiki about this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number